# Persisting "Unfortunately, Keyguard has stopped." error pops on HP Slate 8 Plus

Tags: boot, system-error, hp

HP Slate 8 Plus displays

> Unfortunately, Keyguard has stopped.

The tablet is somewhat active: it displays in the background the visible WLANs. When I hit OK in the message, it returns immediately.

What can I do to use this tablet again?
(Factory reset is an option)